# How to specify label and description fields in CKAN "datastore_create" API request

Tags: javascript, ckan

Im creating a datastore using CKAN API, but CKAN is ignoring the `label` and `description` properties:

```js
const fields = [
  {
    id: "id_unique",
    type: "text",
    label: "label of id_unique", // CKAN ignoring this property
    description: "description of id_unique", // CKAN ignoring this property
  },
  {
    id: "latitude",
    type: "text",
    label: "label of latitude", // CKAN ignoring this property
    description: "description of latitude", // CKAN ignoring this property
  },
  {
    id: "longitude",
    type: "text",
    label: "label of longitude", // CKAN ignoring this property
    description: "description of longitude", // CKAN ignoring this property
  },
]

await clientAction('datastore_create', {
  package_id,
  resource_id,
  force,
  fields,
  records,
  primary_key,
})
```

Result:

[image]

How can I send the "label" and "description" properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution. It's specified in a `info` field:

```js
const fields = [
  {
    id: "id_unique",
    type: "text",
    info: {
      notes: "description of id_unique",
      label: "label of id_unique",
    }
  },
  {
    id: "latitude",
    type: "text",
    info: {
      notes: "description of latitude",
      label: "label of latitude",
    }
  },
  {
    id: "longitude",
    type: "text",
    info: {
      notes: "description of longitude",
      label: "label of longitude",
    }
  },
]
```